# Kibana visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I have a list of companies information in elasticsearch `my_index/company`.

```
"hits": [
    ...
    {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "company",
        "_id": "11893",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            ...
            "financial": [
                {
                    "year": 2015,
                    "income": 1001
                },
                {
                    "year": 2016,
                    "income": 1002
                },
                {
                    "year": 2017,
                    "income": 1003
                },
                {
                    "year": 2018,
                    "income": 1004
                },
            ],
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I need to create in Kibana a visualization that should show average income of companies by year.

[image: Kibana income visualization]

Is there a way to chain `financial` of all companies in one list?

Is need to index `financial` into another type?

How should look setting of that visualization?

Thanks

Comment: To achieve what you want I would clearly index financial data into it own index. Kibana doesn't work well with nested elements, and even less in visualizations.

Comment: I think maybe it can.But all I've done is that the X-axis is the year, and the Y-axis is income sum.